# Installing pyglet on ubuntu 12.04 fails with nosuchconfig exception

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to install pyglet on ubuntu 12.04 and on installing it I get `NoSuchConfigException:No standard config is available` . I tried installing it also from package website on debian but even that did not help.

If anybody would like me to print the output of python -m pyglet.info() I can do that too.

Comment: were you `pip install`ing it?

Comment: @Andbdrew I did pip install first,then I think I removed it and did a sudo-apt get which again I removed and did sudo dpkg installation

Comment: whoa. that's a lot of installing! Was the error you posted from pip?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this exact problem on my ubuntu 12.04 by installing the following deb package :
http://packages.debian.org/sid/python-pyglet